# Neo4j OGM find node with their related nodes

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have one to many relationship(Model 1->N Field), I want find all model with their fields. but the model's fields is empty object.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Model {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "ModelField", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
}

@NodeEntity
public class Field {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
}

public interface ModelRepo extends Neo4jRepository<Model, String>{
}

public ModelRepo mr;

Iterable<Model> models = mr.findALl();

// the model's fields is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

I just reconstructed your scenario basing on your correct code and it works fine. I assume by populating your data something went wrong. Because that piece of code is missing, I can’t point you to the concrete reason. To help you nevertheless, I outline my steps to retrieve your field nodes.

Adding a FieldRepo repository:

```
public interface FieldRepo extends Neo4jRepository<Field, String> {    
}
```

Populating your scenario:

```
Model model = new Model("modelId1", "Model1");

Field field = new Field("fieldId1", "Field1");
model.getFields().add(field);

Field field2 = new Field("fieldId2", "Field2");
model.getFields().add(field2);

modelRepo.save(model);
fieldRepo.save(field);
fieldRepo.save(field2);
```

Retrieving your information:

```
Iterable<Model> resultModels = modelRepo.findAll();
for (Model resultModel : resultModels) {
  System.out.println("Model: " + resultModel.getId() + " " + resultModel.getName());
  for (Field resultField : resultModel.getFields()) {
    System.out.println("\tField: " + resultField.getId() + " " + resultField.getName());
  }
}
```

Which results in the following, your expected output:

```
Model: modelId1 Model1
    Field: fieldId1 Field1
    Field: fieldId2 Field2
```

[Result - graphical representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bePN.png)

I hope that this information proves helpful. Please don't hesitate to ask any unclear items.